# How to make `cake test` return error exit code when some test fails

Tags: clojure

It seems `cake test` always returns 0 to the shell, even when some tests fail. This is probably fine for human, but causes problem in continuous integration. Is there anyway to make cake test return non-0 when some test fails?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [`grep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep):

```
cake test | grep -qve '0 tests failed'
```

Replace "0 tests failed" with a string that clearly determines that all tests passed fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how good is an answer after 2 years, but looks like the solution to this is explained here:

https://www.hiddentao.com/archives/2011/12/21/instructing-cakefile-to-exit-with-error-if-a-vows-test-fails/

What I understand is that cake by itself is very lightweight and doesn't do anything about returning a proper exit code. But by looking for a couple of clues like presence of "✗ Broken" in the output or checking the exit code of the spec runner itself, you can instruct cake to return "1", so that your CI understands that the tests failed.